# Nonlinear ODE with square root

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Self learning ODE's I ran into another non linear equation which I cannot seem to solve
$$tx'(t)-x(t)-\sqrt{t^2+x^2(t)}=0$$
dividing by $t$
$$x'(t)-\frac{1}{t}x(t)-\frac{\sqrt{t^2+x^2(t)}}{t}=0$$

the only ways I know how to solve non linear differential equations is bernoulli's substitution and ordinary substitutions and it feels like there is a trick substitution here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$tx'(t)-x(t)-\sqrt{t^2+x^2(t)}=0$$

$$\frac {tx'(t)-x(t)}{t^2}- \frac {\sqrt{t^2+x^2(t)}} {t^2}=0$$

$$(\frac x t)'- \frac {\sqrt{1+\frac {x^2(t)}{t^2}} }{t}=0$$

Substitue $ v=\frac x t$

$$v'- \frac {\sqrt{1+v^2}} {t}=0$$

$$\int \frac {dv}{\sqrt{1+v^2}}=\int \frac {dt} t=\ln(t)+K$$

Answer (score 1):

Setting $$x'(t)=v(t)+t\frac{dv(t)}{dt}$$
then we get
$$-\sqrt{t^2+t^2v(t)^2}+t\left(t\frac{dv}{dt}+v(t)\right)-tv(t)=0$$ this simplifies to
$$t\left(t\frac{dv(t)}{dt}-\sqrt{v(t)^2+1}\right)=0$$
and we can write
$$\int\frac{\frac{dv(t)}{dt}}{\sqrt{v(t)^2+1}}dt=\int\frac{1}{t}dt$$
can you finish?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose u=$x(t)\over t$. Then u$'$=$tx^{'}(t)-x(t)\over t^{2}$. The equation then could be easily converted to $u^{'} \over \sqrt {1+u^{2}} $=$1 \over t$. The rest is straight forward.